# Update 10 dynamic text fields with unique, but unfriendly names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to insert characters (from a simple variable or whatever) into text fields that look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="customPlugin[2127][textinput][comment]" size="10" value="" class="vmcustom-textinput">
```

There will be up to ten of these on a page and they will run 2127, 2128, 2129 etc.
I am again having a devil of a time trying to get jQuery or JavaScript to select the item with this name ( customPlugin[2127][textinput][comment] )

Comment: So what have you tried so far? And do you have control over the way the inputs are generated?

Comment: Must you use just the `name` attribute for this? Can you try `data` attributes e.g. `data-textinput`, `data-comment='My comment'`. Just a suggestion, but it seems that stuffing everything into the `name` attribute seems inflexible and difficult to work with.

Comment: Is the `[textinput][comment]` part fixed? If so, then `$('.vmcustom-textinput[name^="customPlugin"]')` might work. It uses a CSS3 [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to select all the `<input>`s with a _name_ attribute starting with _customPlugin_.

Comment: It also depends on other elements on this page. if those are the only input elements that end with [comment] in the name, you can use a selector like `$('input[name$="[comment]"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('[name="customPlugin[2127][textinput][comment]"]');`

That should work...

`document.querySelector('[name="customPlugin[2127][textinput][comment]"]');`

Seems to work as well.

EDIT: Removed the extra escapes for [ and ] after some testing. I just assumed they were needed, but didn't check.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `[` and `]` characters? `\[` in a JS string means `[`.

Comment: Well what do you know! Escapism isn't really even needed here. I just supposed they're needed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you wrap the value of the name attribute in quotes, as it contains special characters:

```
$('input[name="customPlugin[2127][textinput][comment]"]').val('your insertion')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name="customPlugin[2127][textinput][comment]"]')//this will work
```

reference [attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)